# How to move tab bar in empathy?

Tags: empathy

Empathy is a rather nice IM client and I like the included themes, but I don't see how to move my tabs in my conversation windows to the bottom of the window instead of the top.. any ideas?

Comment: if by getting the tab at the bottom, you are aiming for usability, may I suggest that you use the `Ctrl + PgUp/PgDn` combination to cycle between tabs.

Comment: thanks, but the reason I wanted this was so I could put the window at the bottom of my screen and keep my terminal windows just slightly higher - this way, when someone contacts me the colored tab is evident.  The reason it doesn't work as well at the top is because the chat window already has other things at the top of it, so it takes up much more vertical space to accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it can only be done by modifying and recompiling the source.

It's looks like a trivial change, but you will need some minimum background in programming. This is the important [file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/maverick/empathy/maverick/annotate/head%3A/src/empathy-chat-window.c). In the 2051 line they create the notebook. You will need to add a line like this afterwards:

```
gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos (GTK_NOTEBOOK (priv->notebook), GTK_POS_BOTTOM);
```

Note that I didn't test it, it will likely work, but...

Comment: If you make this change yourself and commit the bounty is yours! :)

Comment: They are not likely to accept this in trunk just because you like more the tabs in the bottom ;). Anyway, maybe, not sure, don't take this as a promise, if I get bored (only if) in the weekend I'll made a deb for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with the default Empahty package from Ubuntu Maverick.

There's nothing like this in the menus, and the schema installed:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.Empathy.gschema.xml
```

does not mention anything like this.